# Is it possible to use multiple 3g dongles simultaneously?

Tags: wireless-networking, 3g, dongle

Im going to move to Africa and needs fast connection. Several providers have 3g. I wondered if I could buy 2 or 3 3G dongles to get the speed up? Is it possible to set this up in any software or router?

Comment: directly to your pc, yes.  I havent seen a router with USB support, with more than 1 port

Answer (score 4):

You could, but it will not be as straightforward as it seems. Each USB dongles creates its own network, and it will have its own external IP address. You would then need to route calls to one interface or to the other, according to some rules, which you would need to create.

For simple cases, it could be OK: you could route everything that goes to your company via dongle 1, and all public internet through dongle 2. This can be done at operating system level without further requirements.

However, if you want to achieve load balancing, it will require some dedicated component which would route traffic through one dongle to the other. It would need to be smart enough to keep each "session" on the same dongle, because visiting a site from two different IPs, especially if you are logged in, will not work.

I found this: http://www.peplink.com/max-mobile-router/compare/ which may help you as a starting point.

Also this is an interesting project: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/new-router-combines-your-home-and-mobile-networks-into-one-faster-pipe/

Comment: That was very very helpful. I think a couple of powerful modems with great antennas and this product: Peplink Balance 30 Multi-WAN Gigabit Router, will make an excellent solution :-)

Comment: Hi, look at this: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/new-router-combines-your-home-and-mobile-networks-into-one-faster-pipe/

Comment: "visiting a site from two different IPs, especially if you are logged in, will not work." <-- this is incorrect.  Browser cookies eliminate this hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to successfully do this using two 3g broadband routers and 2 3g broadband dongles. 
1. setup both routers to use the 3G dongles as normal.
2. On one router setup the wireless for bridging. This extends your wireless connect throughout your home but as a consequence it doubled my broadband speed from 1.5MB to 3Mb. 
Only problem with this is its using twice as much of my metered data connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on a similar situation, after some research, the best approaches I have seen so far are zeroshell https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/141349-zeroshell-foss-networking-appliance and http://speedify.com/.

I'm doing this because I live on a rural area where only mobile internet is available and I run a small business, so I need a channel to connect to my router and provide internet to my home network. Now i'm testing speedify (time constraints to go through the config of zeroshell now), basically I took and old computer, connected two usb modems and installed speedify and shared internet through RJ45 between the laptop and the router.

I just finished this set up this morning and been testing, but so far general internet works nicely (good connection for 4 laptops on normal browsing), so far the only problem seems related to "direct" connections like skype, or screen sharing, for those, the connection actually improved when we turned of speedify and connected just by on usb modem. Will add more info as I get more results.